# vba/vb6 prevent PowerPoint screenupdating

Tags: vba, vb6, powerpoint

I'm using the code [here](http://skp.mvps.org/ppt00033.htm) for preventing PPT screen updating

It works well under Win7 and office2013 but seems not to apply to Win10 and Office2016. I have of course added the case "16"

Any idea?

Comment: VBA is not VB6.

Comment: @Bob77 VBA is the language behind Visual Basic. VB6 was merely an IDE wrapped around VBA.

Comment: I have tested the code you referred to in PPT16 on Win 10. It appears that the Win API calls don't have any effect, but don't error either. In earlier versions you couldn't have two presentations open side by side and the window would lock up if moved to a different screen. PPT16 behaves differently. Makes me wonder if that is the cause.

Comment: No, VB6 is not "VBA wrapped in an IDE."  Your information is incorrect.